# Does PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage takes its performance toll? Does fetches keys from there once at startup or at each call?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I want to store my data in Blob storage. To do so I need at least call:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri("<blobUriWithSasToken>"));
}
```

Now the question is, do they keys are being fetched at app startup or they're always fetched from the blob each time they're needed?

Then the same if I decide to protect those keys with a key that relies in Key-Vault does ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault access key-vault which is slow only at startup or at each call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source codes and test demo, it will just fetch the key at the start  from there once at startup.

Some part of the service injection:

```
    //You could find all the key management related service is registered as the Singleton.
    private static void AddDataProtectionServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (OSVersionUtil.IsWindows())
        {
            services.TryAddSingleton<IRegistryPolicyResolver, RegistryPolicyResolver>();
        }

        services.TryAddEnumerable(
            ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IConfigureOptions<KeyManagementOptions>, KeyManagementOptionsSetup>());
        services.TryAddEnumerable(
            ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IConfigureOptions<DataProtectionOptions>, DataProtectionOptionsSetup>());

        services.TryAddSingleton<IKeyManager, XmlKeyManager>();
        services.TryAddSingleton<IApplicationDiscriminator, HostingApplicationDiscriminator>();
        services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IHostedService, DataProtectionHostedService>());

        // Internal services
        services.TryAddSingleton<IDefaultKeyResolver, DefaultKeyResolver>();
        services.TryAddSingleton<IKeyRingProvider, KeyRingProvider>();
```

Besides, I have created a test demo to store the key to the blob storage  and use fiddler to capture the read key http request.

You could find it will just read once.

[image]